# None SPD Cluster Tables in SAS 9?

Tags: sas

I am trying to build a cluster table but have just discovered/realised that Proc SPDO is not present in Base SAS version 9 as so:

```
proc SPDO library = clusters;
cluster create mycluster
mem = member1;
mem = member2;
mem = member3;
...
quit;
```

Is there a way to build a cluster object using base libraries and tables in this version of SAS?

Thanks

Comment: Proc SPDO falls under the SAS Scalable Performance Server license. Do you have this specific product?

Comment: Hi there. No sadly not. I only have Base SAS version 9.0...

Comment: I'm going to assume you don't actually have 9.0 but 9.04? At any rate then you don't have access to the proc. what are you trying to accomplish? Perhaps theirs a workaround.

Comment: basically trying to build large tables of 100 million plus rows just using base sas 9 and no server and have reasonable response times when querying it.